# sendmail: add domain to local usernames, masquerade hostname

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, email-server, sendmail

I would like to send mails to local users (`mail username -s test <<< "test"`) and let sendmail add the domain. Sending mail to the full address (`mail username@domain.tld -s test <<< "test"`) works, but if I only specify `username` then the mail is send to `username@hostname.domain.tld` which is not valid.

I [read about masquerading](https://thegreyblog.blogspot.de/2009/11/configuring-sendmail-to-masquerade-your.html) and added this to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`domain.tld')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`hostname')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`hostname.domain.tld')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`domain.tld')dnl
```

restarted `sendmail` (`sendmail.cf` is automatically rebuild) but `/var/log/mail.log` still tells me that `sendmail` sends to the address with the hostname included.

How can I add `@domain.tld` to local usernames?

**Edit**

Requested output:

```
# as username
$ /usr/sbin/sendmail -Ac -bv username
Notice: -bv may give misleading output for non-privileged user
username... deliverable: mailer relay, host [127.0.0.1], user username@hostname.domain.tld
```

Comment: What is reported by the `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bv username` executed by non root user?

Comment: @AnFi: I added the output of the command as a normal user and as root with sudo.

Comment: Sorry, my "lack of precision". Report output of `/usr/sbin/sendmail -Ac -bv username`.  It should show you email address passed to sendmail daemon listening at 127.0.0.1:25

Comment: @AnFi: I added this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the masquerading options need to be placed in `/etc/mail/submit.mc`. These were all the lines needed:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`domain.tld')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`hostname')dnl
```

Regenerate submit.cf if that isn't done automatically for you and restart `sendmail` and it works.